# React and Unity

Tags: reactjs, unity-game-engine

Im working on a proyect and i´ve come across some issue I´ve never had before.
I need to integrate to React a Unity program thats already finished and I find this misleading.

[image]

Target editor is my component and inside it I copied the /unity/ folder that has the program.
How can I do this?
Thank you for your time!